# Google Document web-layout view mode similarly in Microsoft's Word

Tags: google-docs

I want to view the document under web-layout view mode the same way as we can do in Microsoft Word.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Pageless Option in Page Setup: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/163380/105287

Answer (score 9):

At this time, there are only two views Print Layout on/off.

Click menu `View > Print layout`

For viewing a document as a web page the only way is to publish the document, but the published version is read only.

**References**
[Publish a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing - Google Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)

Comment: `Print Layout` mode is not helping at all; from my side. I've just tried it.

Comment: @NamGVU Turning it **off** removes the margins between pages

Comment: This! thank you

Answer (score 7):

This question is old and there has been an update.

Go to `File > Page Setup`. You will see the option to select `Pageless`. This is equivalent to the Web Layout of Microsoft Word.

[image: Pageless in Google Document]

Comment: It becomes an equivalent to Web Layout in MS Word only after choosing "Full" in "Format" > "Text width".

Answer (score 3):

If the aim is to view more page with fewer margins, the closest work-around is to change the page size to something bigger. This can always be reverted.

1. `File` > `Page Setup`
2. Take note of existing settings - specifically `Orientation` and `Paper size`, such that they can be reverted later
3. Change the `Orientation` to `Landscape`
4. Under `Paper size`, select `A3 (29.7cm x 42.0cm)`
5. Press `OK`

Answer (score 2):

You can deselect View → Print Layout and then install the addon "stylus" and make your own style to get rid of the dotted lines that separate each page:

```
.kix-page-compact::before {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an option.

But you can use google docs in your phone to get a similar visual effect to web layout in word, that is: larger text that fits the screen better. At least that's the reason I use that word feature.

Comment: How??? when i view a google doc on my iPhone in Safari, the margins are so big it squishes the text in the middle & images do not scale down.

Comment: unfortunately, the answer for me is - if you have to view it on a phone, you must use the Google Docs APP. doing that fixes all the formatting issues i was having.